# Sum everything to left

Tags: excel, sum, rows

I am looking for the code to sum everything to the left of the active cell. My purpose for this: I have a created a macro to reconcile events. Works great for any events with 8 columns of "sessions", however some events have more "sessions", therefore if my SUM(A1:H1) formula will not work if say the event has say 10 columns of sessions. My ideal formula would add everything to the left of the active cell wither I have 6, 7, or 15 columns. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `OFFSET`, but it's volatile, so I prefer `INDEX`:

```
=SUM($A1:INDEX(1:1,COLUMN()-1))
```

This says to sum from A1 to the cell in Row 1 whose index is one less than the column the formula is in.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great, and I do apologize for being slow this morning, however how can I get this to loop? Here is my code. I do have a header row so I start with A2. Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: Cells.Find(What:="Sum of Sessions", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).range("A1").Select
    
    Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = Empty
    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(A2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMN()-1))"

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments as well. I do complete the loop in the code, what I meant was while this is looping, it is obviously only computing row 2.